# how do i make a file name which has date info in it into list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

I want to read my file name which has date and time info in it and make them in to a list.

```
20200805180433_254566010220H000231NX285--0401202002W.TXT
```

This is my file name. The front part is date then time

I want my output to be something like

```
DAT=2020/08/05 ZEI=18:04:33 SN=254566010220H000231NX285--0401202002W
```

and I also want them to be in a list, something like this

```
info[0]="DAT=2020/08/05", info[1]="ZEI=18:04:33", info="SN=254566010220H000231NX285--0401202002W"
```

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We expect to see your coding attempt, and a clear explanation of where you're stuck.  Most of what you ask is already covered in many tutorials on string handling and `datetime` or simple formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy. Assume, i've a file name that is in a, then i do string manipulation to get desired output.

[image]

Comment: thank a lot that is what i wanted. im still kinda new to python and coding, i just started python for 4 days. i didnt know filename is like a list already. big PP